# Using both $in and $elemMatch using the C# Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm having a hard time translating a working `MongoDB` query to the C# driver's untyped equivalent.
The query:

```
{
    "Field" : { "$elemMatch" : { "$in" : ["Hamster"]}}
}
```

What I have:

```
Query.ElemMatch("Field", Query.In("", new BsonArray(new[] { "Hamster" })));
```

Which generates:

```
{
    "Field" : { "$elemMatch" : { "" : { "$in" : ["Hamster"] }}}
}
```

That's pretty close but i can't figure out how to remove the name from the $in query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it should be possible, but the way the helper methods are structured I can't see an easy way of constructing that query directly.

The only way I could recreate the desired query is by doing variations of the following:

```
var queryDocument = QueryDocument.Parse("{\"$in\" : [\"Hamster\"]}");
var nestedQueryDocument = Query.ElemMatch("Field", new QueryDocument(queryDocument));
```

Creates the following output

```
{
    "Field" : { "$elemMatch" : { "$in" : ["Hamster"]}}
}
```

Not the most elegant of solutions though.

Answer (score 2):

```
Query.ElemMatch("Field", new QueryDocument("$in", new BsonArray(new[] { "Hamster" })));
```