# Querying an array of arrays with the MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

My document look like :

```
"ID" : "fruit1",
"Keys" : [
           ["apple", "carrot"]
           ["banana"]
         ]
```

How do I query for Keys = "carrot" using MongoDB C# driver?

I can do it in shell  :

```
db.multiArr.find({'Keys':{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:['carrot']}}}})
```

I Found it from here : [Querying an array of arrays in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629692/querying-an-array-of-arrays-in-mongodb?newreg=0f76e0af29c64fcab2777e9506b6e22f)

But I don't have succeed written it using c# driver.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using both $in and $elemMatch using the C# Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176263/using-both-in-and-elemmatch-using-the-c-sharp-driver)

Comment: You basically can't in a safe way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed with something not very biutifull :

```
var q = Query.ElemMatch("Keys", Query.In("$elemMatch", new List<BsonValue> { "carrot" }));
```

Comment: How can query the Keys array if it was an object array instead of an string array ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

Note: I didn't test this.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(); // connect to localhost
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
var db = server.GetDatabase("foo");
var col = db.GetCollection<RawBsonDocument>("multiArr");

// Query = {'Keys':{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:['carrot']}}}}
BsonDocument query = new BsonDocument{ 
    "Keys", new BsonDocument {
      "$elemMatch", new BsonDocument {
          "$elemMatch", new BsonDocument {
              "$in", new BsonArray().Add("carrot")
          }
      }
    }
};
col.Find(query);
```

More info: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#csharp-driver-tutorial